# Capture checkbox event in the recyclerview

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have `MainViewModel` where it shows all the person as a list using recyclerview. Each person has age, gender, name property and also checkbox in order to delete it.

I could not able to figure out how I could able to capture user checkbox event in the `MainViewModel`?

**MainView.axml**

```
    <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/checkbox"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      local:MvxBind="Checked IsAllSelected" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Name"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Age" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Gender" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <MvxRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/personRecyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/persontemplate"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; ItemClick ItemSelected" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

**PersonTemplate.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:layout_height="60dp">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chked"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    local:MvxBind="Checked IsSelected; Click CheckBoxSelectionCommand;" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Name"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Age"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Age"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Gender"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Gender
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to update `IsDeleteBtnShow`  based on the `checkbox` selection for each item.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public bool IsAllSelected
{
  get { return _isAllSelected; }
  set
  {
    _isAllSelected= value;
    Items.ForEach(x => x.IsSelected = _isAllSelected);
    IsDeleteBtnShow = _isAllSelected;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsAllSelected);
  }
 }
```

I have the following viewmodel which is used by `RecyclerView` to tabulate person as a list.

**PersonRecyclerViewModel.cs**

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return _isSelected; }
    set
    {
        _isSelected = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsSelected);
    }
}

public ICommand CheckBoxSelectionCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand(() =>
        {
            var isChecked = IsSelected;
        });
    }
}

public static PersonViewModel CreateViewModel(Person person)
{
   return new PersonViewModel 
   {
      IsSelected = person.IsSelected,
      Age= person.Age,
      Gender= person.Gender,
      Name= entity.Name,
   };
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass a callback or command to the cration of the ItemViewModel. `CreateViewModel(Person person, Action<PersonViewModel> checkboxSelectedCallback)` and use it directly as or in `CheckBoxSelectionCommand`. Something like this:

**CheckBoxSelectionCommand**

```cs
public ICommand CheckBoxSelectionCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand(() =>
        {
            var isChecked = IsSelected;
            ParentCheckBoxSelectionCallback(this);              
        });
    }
}
```

**CreateViewModel**

```cs
public static PersonViewModel CreateViewModel(Person person, Action<PersonViewModel> checkboxSelectedCallback)
{
    return new PersonViewModel 
    {
        IsSelected = entity.IsSelected,
        Age = entity.Age,
        ParentCheckBoxSelectionCallback = checkboxSelectedCallback,
        Gender= entity.Gender,
        Name= entity.Name,
    };
}
```

**MainViewModel**

```cs
// only create once. 
_checkedChangedCallback = (person =>  
{
    // do what you have to do if a item got selected
});

// where you create persons
CreateViewModel(person, _checkedChangedCallback );
```

Comment: Could you please check my update how I am using the `CreateViewModel`? Could you please elaborate `ParentCheckBoxSelectionCommand` ?

Comment: `CreateViewModel` used for conversion and how it gets two parameters as an input? Could you please check my update section ?

Comment: Just change it to: `....ConvertAll(person => PersonRecyclerViewModel.CreateViewModel(person, _checkedChangedCommand) );`

Comment: is  `ICommand _checkedChangedCommand` ? how to initialize _checkedChangedCommand

Comment: In the MainViewModel I have added  `public MvxCommand<PersonViewModel> _checkedChangedCommand;` it still says `_checkedChangedCommand` does not exist in the current context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111478/discussion-between-sven-michael-stube-and-hotspring).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this without adding Actions or any logic in your model is to make your model implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**:

`class PersonRecyclerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged`

The quickest way to do it is using [Fody PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) because you´ll get the whole implementation of the interface by just adding an attribute to the model:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
class PersonRecyclerViewModel {}
```

In your ViewModel, when you get or refresh data source, a for loop would listen for item property changes:

```
foreach(var item in Items)
{
    var n = (INotifyPropertyChanged)item;
    n.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
}

private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    if(propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
    {
       // do whatever you need here
    }
}
```